# How display one line and sort a file in unix shell?

Tags: unix, sorting, row, ksh

I have this kind of file:

```
TAB  |  STAT |  RECORDS
------------------------
TAB1
DUPKEY
26
TAB1
DUPKEY
26
TAB1
DUPKEY
26
TAB1
DUPKEY
26
TAB1
DUPKEY
26
TAB1
DUPKEY
26
TAB1
DUPKEY
26
TAB1
DUPKEY
26
```

As you can see there are multiple lines and they are the same. What i need is make a sort of this file called report.dat and the output will be

```
TAB  |  STAT |  RECORDS
------------------------
TAB1   DUPKEY     26
```

How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
# print the first 2 lines
sed 2q file
# skip the first 2 lines, join 3 lines into 1, then get unique lines
sed 1,2d file | paste - - - | sort -u
```

```
TAB  |  STAT |  RECORDS
------------------------
TAB1    DUPKEY  26
```

`paste` joins with a tab character by default

Comment: It doesn't work. This instructions are inside an if condition that is inside a while cicle.. Could be a problem?